# Double Integral Confusion

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

A buddy was asking me for help with one of his MV Calc problems, and I ended up getting the same answer as him so I figured I'd ask it here...

**Question** Find $$\iint_{R} (x-1) \, dA$$ where $R$ is the region enclosed by $y=x$ and $y=x^3$ in the first quadrant. So naturally I told him to compute $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^3}^{x} (x-1) \, dy \, dx$$ as $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$ and $y$ from $x^3$ to $x$. Using this integral, we got $\frac{-7}{60}$. His textbook gives an answer of $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get also:  $ \ \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \ . $  Is this from a textbook?  If so, which one and what edition?  Is it from a computer-homework system? (I've lost count of how many mistakes I've dealt with on those...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Anton: Calculus A New Horizon, 6th ed

Comment: Huh, by sixth edition, someone generally catches just about all of the answer errors -- _unless_ it's a revised or replaced problem over the fifth edition... (And I don't see some sign error among the terms that would have lead the anonymous solver to their answer.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Apparently, it's now on the 10th edition...  (evidently, some more errors were found `:P`)

Comment: My experience is that for books that have run over numerous editions (*gasp* Thomas is up to _12th_), the steady-state percentage of answer errors is about $ \ \frac{1}{3} $ % to  $ \ \frac{1}{2} $ % .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As mentioned in the comments, your answer is correct.**  I'll provide a solution here for future readers.

First, draw a picture.  I'm going to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y=%20x%5E3,%20y=x) to show one online--it should be simple enough to graph by hand.  We can see the intersections are at $(0, 0)$ and a $(1, 1)$.  Thus, we have our limits of integration.  Evaluation is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_{x^3}^x(x-1)\,dy\,dx &= \int_0^1y(x-1)\Bigg|_{x^3}^x\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1(x-x^3)(x-1)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1(-x^4+x^3 + x^2-x)\,dx\\
&= -\frac{x^5}{5} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg|_0^1 \\
&= \frac{-1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{2}\\
&= \frac{-7}{60}
\end{align}$$